# O(m) all-pairs shortest paths algorithm for directed acylical graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

An exercise I'm working on asks me to devise an $O(m)$ algorithm for the all-pairs shortest paths of the graph $G = (V, A)$, where $(v_i, v_j) \in A$ implies $i < j$.

I'm wondering whether this is at all possible, since so far I've not been able to come up with any suitable $O(m)$ algorithm and an internet search has come up short as well..

I think that you have to cycle through every edge $(v_i, v_j)$, but then (if we call $u_{ij}$ the shortest distance between $v_i$ and $v_j$) you have to calculate $u_{kj} = \min\{ u_{kj}, u_{ki} + l_{ij} \}$ for every $k = \{ 1, 2, ..., j - 1 \}$, every time. Clearly this is not an $O(m)$ algorithm (I think it is an $O(1/2(m - 1)m)$ algorithm).

If this would be a shortest path problem, where only $u_{1j}$ has to be determined, this could be done in $O(m)$ steps, using the method described above I think.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you finding the shortest path between all pairs of vertices? If you are just looking for the shortest path between any two particular vertices, you can use breadth first, or depth first searches.

Comment: yeah, between all pairs. It already says that in the title, but I updated it in the text as well ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see it now

Comment: There are $O(n^2)$ vertex pairs, which is the size of the output.  So the algorithm can't go faster than that.  Can we assume that the graph is dense - that is, $m \in \Theta(n^2)$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, but sure, let's assume that the graph is dense.

Comment: Oh well even assuming that I haven't been able to come up with an answer.  I'd be curious about the answer so if you ever get it, I'd be glad if you posted it here if you don't mind !  If this is homework one remark for the teacher would be the following : Take a directed path of length $n$ (ie the digraph $v_1 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow v_n$).  Each $v_i$ has a path to $v_j$ whenever $j > i$, and so there are $O(n^2)$ paths, even though there are $m = n - 1$ arcs. So a $O(m)$ algorithm does not seem feasible, as the ouput has asymptotically more than $m$ arcs.